# Failed to resolve: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions-ktx:2.0.0-alpha1

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-livedata

I am trying to understand ViewModel and LiveData concepts in android. I am making a practice project but when i added `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions-ktx:2.0.0-alpha1'` line in my app level gradle file it shows me

> Failed to resolve:
>   androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions-ktx:2.0.0-alpha1.

I have searched on google for solution and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50781666/7804719) answer, it works when i compile only viewmodel library but if i compile extensions library using same method as `implementation group: 'androidx.lifecycle', name:'lifecycle-extensions-ktx', version: '2.0.0-alpha1'`, it shows the same error as above.
I have also tried to find it on Maven repositories site [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-extensions) but i didn't have any information for how to compile it.

## UPDATE

#### App Level Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***************"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation group: 'androidx.lifecycle', name:'lifecycle-extensions-ktx', version: '2.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation group: 'androidx.lifecycle', name:'lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx', version: '2.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Comment: You should add `google()
        jcenter()`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50890280/3395198

Comment: I have already added it.

Comment: show us your app-level `build.gradle`

Comment: Please look at the update@YosiPramajaya

Comment: You need to show the top-level build.gradle,specifically the repositories block.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### **UPDATE**

As per [@Dr.jacky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421467/dr-jacky)'s comment and Android Developers Documentation,

> The APIs in lifecycle-extensions have been deprecated. Instead, add dependencies for the specific Lifecycle artifacts you need.

More Info at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle

---

I have found the answer. As `Thunder Knight` said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50781666/7804719) `it seems to be that the repository was emptied somehow. Hence, you can not download it from the repository.`. I agree with this and so i was looking for answer on [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com) and i found it [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-extensions/2.0.0-alpha1). I have to add

> implementation group: 'androidx.lifecycle', name: 'lifecycle-extensions', version: '2.0.0-alpha1'

line for adding lifecycle-extensions and also i was adding `-ktx` in name of library but it was the mistake. In [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components) they have not commented to add `-ktx` in line of `lifecycle-extensions`.

Credits:- [@Thunder Knight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50781666/7804719)

Comment: `The APIs in lifecycle-extensions have been deprecated. Instead, add dependencies for the specific Lifecycle artifacts you need.` -> https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle

Answer (score 14):

The current version is 2.2.0

use -ktx for kotlin implementation
and kapt for annotationProcesssor

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0'
```

Check the developer site for more information

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components

Answer (score 3):

Just dont use -ktx in lifecycle-extensions. There is no separate '-ktx' version of the dependency unlike in viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

Add these line

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
```

and comment these lines

```
// testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
//androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
//androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i was trying to using room with LiveData. and all i did was remove the suspend key word from the query method.

Reference: [post in forums.bignerdranch.com](https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/solved-execution-failed-for-task-kaptdebugkotlin/17431)

Answer (score 0):

Error:

```
Failed to resolve: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.3.1
```

Solution:

> The APIs in lifecycle-extensions have been deprecated. Instead, add dependencies for the specific Lifecycle artifacts you need.

More details: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

This is specifically for React-Natice. if you run into Adroidx issues when trying to run the android app in vscode, open the android folder of the reactive-native app in android studio, let it do it magic and you just need to resolve any issues android studio highlights, once that is done close android studio and try run the app in vscode again